# Python will print list value but says list is empty when trying to access values (using .pop() or indexing[0] etc.)

Tags: python, pandas, list, xlsx

## Background

I am reading in data from a .xlsx spreadsheet using *Pandas 1.3.4* and *Python 3.9.6*.

I want data for each item based on a `code` in the 'Code' column so I am first isolating a row in the dataframe (`df`) using:

```
row = df.loc[df['Code'] == code]
```

To then get individual values in the row I am accessing them using indexing and their headers as follows:

```
barcode = row['Barcode'].values.tolist()
```

I am using `.values` as I otherwise get a cumbersome line number and datatype output. I am using `.tolist()` so that I can effectively access the actual barcode rather than a scientific notation interpretation. Note that this means `barcode` should be a list with a single value.

## Problem

Here is my problem, when I print `barcode` I get a sensible output, e.g.: `[72934728491]` *(note this is not an actual barcode, but an example 11 digits)*

**Update:** `len(barcode)` returns 1 and `type(barcode)` returns `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` or `<class 'list'>` if I've used `.tolist()`

However, if I try to access the value inside the list using `barcode[0]` or `barcode.pop()` I get errors saying that the index is out of range or that `.pop()` cannot be used on an empty list.

Bizarrely, if I write a for loop to get the value out of the list it works just fine:

```
for item in barcode:
    print(item)
```

## Question

Please can someone explain why this is happening and how to actually fix it (rather than having to write a for loop for every single column value I need to access on the row).

## Update (More code as requested)

I have tried to construct a Minumum Viable Example to help, but am struggling to replicate the problem in other code for now, this is the section where I dissect the dataframe, unfortunately I cannot show the section where I read in the df as it contains private info, but the spreadsheet reads into the df 'normally':

```
for code in new_items:
    row = df.loc[df['Code'] == code] # row for a single item code
    product_display_name = row['Product Display Name'].values
    product_type = row['Product Type'].values
    description = row['Description'].values
    artist = row['Artist'].values
    barcode = row['Barcode'].values.tolist()
    finish = row['Finish'].values
    unit = row['Unit'].values
    country_of_origin = row['Country of Origin'].values
    job_number = row['Job No.'].values
    samples_date = row['Samples Date'].values

print(barcode.pop()) # this does not work
for item in barcode:
    print(item) # this does work
```

Comment: Sounds like your library is overriding things in a way you don't expect. I don't know much about pandas, but you could print(type(barcode)) to get a head start on looking up the documentation on that class.

Comment: Try: `barcode = row['Barcode'].astype(str).values.tolist()`

Comment: Will you please show all your code?

Comment: `type(barcode)` is `list` for me - @HmmmCurious your problem is lost on me...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Corralien, I tried that, but it still has the same empty list problem for me.

```type(barcode)``` is ```<class 'numpy.ndarray'>``` for me until I change it to a list using ```.tolist()```.

I will update my question to show more of my code as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be to do with **pandas**' handling of empty cell `NaN` values.

While dataframes display `NaN`, somewhere in the `.values` and `.tolist()` conversion I was losing that info and having empty arrays. This was further complicated by some strange spreadsheet formatting that meant the dataframe had a 0th row of all `NaN` values so my loop never even hit a valid value before failing.